# How to set default value in React native multiselect

Tags: react-native

I met a problem how to set the default value in React native multiselect.

The following is my multiselect code in React Native.

<MultiSelect

```
      data={data}

      value={dataselected}

      onChange={item => {

        setdataSelected(item);

      }}

      renderLeftIcon={() => (     

      )}

      selectedStyle={styles.selectedStyle}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop you can use to set default items.

```
<MultiSelect
      uniqueKey={*your data id here*}
      data={data}
      value={dataselected}
      selectedItems={*your default items here*}
      onChange={item => {
        setdataSelected(item);
      }}
      renderLeftIcon={() => ()}
      selectedStyle={styles.selectedStyle}
    />
```

Also, make sure you have the uniqueKey prop in your component as it is 1 of the 3 necessary props to render the component.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multiple-select